# Erro Spring boot chamada do controller "This application has no explicit mapping for /error"

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

Estou com um problema pois estou aprendendo a utilizar os métodos *GET* e *POST* utilizando o *Spring Boot*, porem apenas um `controller` não estou conseguindo mostrar na tela. Bom estou utilizando o *JSP* já configurei
no `aplication.propertties`.

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

A questão e que tenho 3 tabelas no *MySQL* uma e a treinamento e a outra e cursos

```
@Controller
public class MainControllerCur {
    @Autowired
    AppCursosRepo appRepocur;

    @RequestMapping("/cursos")
    public ModelAndView doHomeCur(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("cursos");
        mv.addObject("listscur",appRepocur.findAll());
        return mv;
    }

}


@Controller
public class MainControllerTr {
    @Autowired
    AppTreinamentoRepo appRepo;

    @RequestMapping("/treinamento")
    public ModelAndView doHome(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
        return mv;
    }
```

Porem esta aqui a funcionário e a unica que não gera visão do servidor quando chamo o *JSP*.

```
@Controller
public class MainControllerFunc {
    @Autowired
    AppFuncionarioRepo appRepofunc;

    @RequestMapping("/funcionario")
    public ModelAndView doHomeFunc(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("funcionario");
        mv.addObject("listsfunc",appRepofunc.findAll());
        return mv;
    }
}
```

O que e estranho e que e exatamente igual as outras duas só muda a chamada `/funcionario` compila normal sem nenhum erro não aparece nenhum log de erro no console.

O erro é sempre este

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Oct 14 01:14:19 BRT 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/jsp/funcionario.jsp
```

Se alguém puder me dar uma explicação ficarei grato.

Comment: Revise os nomes que está usando na view e no controller. Tem certeza que é funcionario e não funcionarios?

Comment: preste atenção na estrutura das pastas, no caso o seu Aplication não pode ficar no mesmo nivel dos outros arquivos. resolvi o meu erro apartir deste link https://www.yawintutor.com/application-has-no-explicit-mapping-for-error-whitelabel-error-page-with-status-404/

Answer (score 0):

É necessário adicionar a dependência:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa completar o mapeamento, você criou um endpoint porém, ele não faz nada.

```
Deveria ser assim: 

       @RestController
       @RequestMapping("/cursos")
    public class MainControllerCur {
        @Autowired
        AppCursosRepo appRepocur;
        @GetMapping(value = "cursos/geral")
        public ModelAndView doHomeCur(){
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("cursos");
            mv.addObject("listscur",appRepocur.findAll());
            return mv;
        }
    
    }
```

Eu só usei um como exemplo.